# How to indent code (or a selection of code) in Visual Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, indentation

I need a "Visual Code" shortcut to indent my code

I tried ton's of shortcuts in Visual Code, no effect, or the wrong effect

I think I need ton's of documentation to find a simple "indent" shortcut, sorry I have no more text to illustrate the problem

Comment: you can use: 
ctrl + ], [   (to add and remove indent)
or 
 tab, shift + tab  (to add and remove indent)

Comment: @debug_dk Why does **Format Document** do what the OP wants

Comment: The shortcut now works, earlier not, tried multiple times. thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can find keyboard shortcuts in VS code settings and search for indent you will find that 
**Indent** `Ctrl`+`]` 
**Outdent** `Ctrl`+`[`
[image]

you can even find keyboard shortcuts from the search bar write `> keyboard shortcuts` and even there is a shortcut to open it `Ctrl` + `K` then `Ctrl` + `S`